# Load only some images from disk cache using Universal Image Loader

Tags: java, android

I am using the Universal Image Loader disk cache feature. I have restricted it to only cache images with the a maximum of 480x320 resolution. This works nicely, but when I tap those images to open the full size images, UIL loads the image from the disk cache and I see a stretched / distorted version of the small cached image.

I want to know how to tell UIL to load the images from disk cache but only for specific images. I have tried searching without luck.

Thanks.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code?

Comment: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/wiki/Useful-Info maybe try, `cacheInMemory(false).cacheOnDisk(false);`

Comment: It seems the only way to do this is to create two instances of ImageLoader which is painfully annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the only answer to this is to create two instances of the ImageLoader. One with disk caching and one without it.